# How to make Windows Phone 7 Prism project?

Tags: windows-phone-7, prism

I'm new to Prism framework and Windows Phone 7, but I'm familiar with Silverlight. I want to use Prism framework to architect my project. I found this [link](http://wp7guide.codeplex.com/) talks about patterns & practices for WP7. However it's seems to be bit complicated, can someone share the WP7 project basic architecture. It will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with the project template from http://bindableapplicationb.codeplex.com/releases/view/80041